# Unity old fonts assets

Tags: unity-game-engine, localization

I havent work with Unity before but now I need to localize Unity application.

I've found string in resources, but when I'm trying to replace it with string on my alphabet(Russian), I haven't see characters, it looks like they are absent in app font assets.

I have tried to replace fonts assests with assets from another Unity app which have russian chars for sure, but with no luck. Looks like at some point Unity have updated the way it supports fonts and have a really old app - it is using Unity 2013 version.

Please point me, where I can find a font asset which will contains russian characters and work for this old Unity app.